# undefiened reference

Tags: c++, vector, makefile

Выдает вот такую ошибку. Объявления вроде есть, а в коде их не видит. 
makefile и код в спойлерах ниже

```
main.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x2b): undefined reference to 
`containers::vector<int>::push_back(int&&)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x45): undefined reference to 
`containers::vector<int>::push_back(int&&)'
main.o: In function `void outarr<int>(containers::vector<int>&)':     
main.cpp   (.text._Z6outarrIiEvRN10containers6vectorIT_EE
[_Z6outarrIiEvRN10containers6vectorIT_EE]+0x22): 
undefined reference to `containers::vector<int>::size()'
main.cpp:
(.text._Z6outarrIiEvRN10containers6vectorIT_EE
[_Z6outarrIiEvRN10containers6vectorIT_EE]+0x3d):  
undefined reference to `containers::vector<int>::operator[](int)'
```

---

makefile:

```
all: vector

vector: main.o vector.o
    g++ main.o vector.o -o vector

main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -c main.cpp

vector.o: vector.cpp
    g++ -c vector.cpp

clear:
    rm -rf *.o
```

main.cpp

```
#include "vector.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace containers;

template<class T>
void outarr(vector<T>& v) {
    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
         std::cout << v[i] << "\t";
} 

int main() {
    vector<int> test;
    test.push_back(0);
    test.push_back(3);
    outarr<int>(test);
    return 0;
}
```

vector.h

```
#ifndef CONTAINER_VECTOR
#define CONTAINER_VECTOR

#include <cstddef>
#include <initializer_list>

namespace containers {

template<class T>
class vector {

private:
    T* array;
    std::size_t vector_size = 0;
    std::size_t vector_capacity;

public:
    vector() {}
    vector(std::initializer_list<T> init);
    vector(std::size_t size);
    vector(vector& other);
    ~vector() { delete[] array; }

    std::size_t size();
    std::size_t capacity();
    void reserve(std::size_t size);

    void push_back(const T& value);
    void push_back(T&& value);
    void insert(std::size_t pos, const T& value);
    void insert(std::size_t pos, T&& value);

    T&   pop_back();
    void clear();
    void erease(std::size_t pos);
    void erease(std::size_t from, std::size_t to);

    T& operator[](int index);
    //T& operator=(T& other);

};

}


#endif
```

vector.cpp

```
#include "vector.h"

#define tplate template<class T>

namespace containers {

tplate
vector<T>::vector(std::initializer_list<T> init) {
    vector_size = init.size();
    array = new T[vector_size];
    for(int i = 0; i < vector_size; ++i)
        array[i] = init[i];
}

tplate
vector<T>::vector(std::size_t size) {
    vector_size = size;
    array = new T[vector_size];
}

tplate
vector<T>::vector(vector& other) {
    vector_size = other.vector_size;
    array = new T[vector_size];
    for(int i = 0; i < vector_size; ++i)
        array[i] = other[i];
}

tplate
std::size_t vector<T>::size() { return vector_size; }

tplate
std::size_t vector<T>::capacity() { return vector_capacity; }

tplate
void vector<T>::reserve(std::size_t size) {
    T* newarr = new T[size];
    for(int i = 0; i < vector_size; ++i)
        newarr[i] = array[i];
    vector_size = size;
    delete[] array;
    array = newarr;
}

tplate
void vector<T>::push_back(const T& value) {
    if(vector_size <= vector_capacity) 
        reserve(++vector_size);
    array[vector_capacity] = value;
    ++vector_capacity;
}

tplate
void vector<T>::push_back(T&& value) {
    if(vector_size <= vector_capacity) 
        reserve(++vector_size);
    T* newel = value;
    array[vector_capacity] = *newel;
    ++vector_capacity;
}

tplate
void vector<T>::insert(std::size_t pos, const T& value) {
    if(pos > vector_capacity) {
        vector_size = pos;
        vector_capacity = pos;
        reserve(vector_size);
    }
    for(int i = vector_size; i > pos+1; --i)
        array[i] = array[i-1];
    array[pos] = value;
} 

tplate
T& vector<T>::operator[](int index) {
    return array[index];
}

} // namespace containers

#undef tplate
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала избавтись от

```
#define tplate template<class T>
```

А так, тело шаблонных функций/классов должно быть в .h файле, дя красоты его можно вынести в отдельный .inl файл и подключить снизу в .h файле.

Либо, сделать явную инстанциацию шаблоного класса для определенного типа в .cpp файле, в том файле где "видно" тела шаблонных методов

```
template class vector<int>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Стандартная ошибка. Реализация шаблона должна быть доступна, без этого не происходит его инстанцирование. Так что переместите код из `vector.cpp` в `vector.h` - иначе происходит следующее: при компиляции `main.cpp` инстанцирования нет (как инстанцировать то, чего незнаешь?), а в `vector.cpp` опять же инстанцирования нет - потому что раз класс не используется - зачем его инстанцировать?

Можно, конечно, явно указать в `vector.cpp` на необходимость инстанцирования для того или иного типа, но это способ не лучший - вдруг понадобится вектор еще какого-то типа?

И еще, на всякий случай - надеюсь, вы знаете, что в

```
void push_back(T&& value);
```

`value` - универсальная ссылка, а не r-ссылка?

Судя по

```
T* newel = value;
array[vector_capacity] = *newel;
```

я вообще не пойму, чем вы ее считаете... Указателем на `T`?

И последнее - вот такие вещи

```
#define tplate template<class T>
```

отнюдь не способствуют пониманию кода, особенно если их становится много. Экономия, не стоящая того. Да и тогда уж хотя бы назовите `TPLATE` - чтоб хотя бы сразу видеть, что это макрос.